# Provided 'undefined' where stream was expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to send chained http requests using Rxjs, but I am getting this error...

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>   TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I want to get location object from my API, then I want to get latitude and longitude based on `location.address`.

```
declare const require : any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapLocationResolver implements Resolve<{location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number }> {

constructor( private locationService: LocationService, 
             private route: ActivatedRoute, 
             private router: Router){}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): {location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number } | Observable<{location: Location, longitude:number, latitude: number }> | Promise<{location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number }> {

    let geocoder = require('geocoder');

    return this.locationService.getLocation(route.params['id']).map(
        (response: Response)=> { return response.json() }
    ).mergeMap(location => geocoder.geocode(location.address, function(err, data){
        let latitude
        let longitude
        if(data.status === 'OK'){
            console.log('Status ok: ')
            console.log(data)
            let results = data.results;
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            console.log(latitude); // PRINTS CORRECT
            console.log(longitude); // PRINTS CORRECT
        }                  
        return {location, longitude, latitude};
    })).catch(error => {
        this.router.navigate(['/not-found'])
        return Observable.throw(error);
    })  
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Whats very weird is that after this error, console prints latitude and longitude correct! ('// PRINTS CORRECT' comment)

EDIT: Yep my mistake, I declared variables in if, but that was not a problem at the end. Posting solution soon.

Comment: Your `latitude` and `longitude` variables are block scoped because of the `let` keyword used. Did you verify this line is working properly? `return {location, longitude, latitude};` Also have you tried to use `map` instead of `mergeMap`? I think that is where the error is coming from

Comment: U cant access `longitude` and `latitude` outside if as you have declared them using `let` thats why `mergemap` returns undefined .. you should move ur return statement inside if.. and return something inside else...

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel @Rahul Thanks! That was not the main problem at the end. Problem is that `geocoder.geocode` has no return value, while `mergemap` is expecting `Promise`, `Observable` etc. Posting answer to my question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it... Problem is that `geocoder.geocode()` function has no return value, while `mergeMap()` is expecting an `Promise`,`Observable` etc, `geocoder.geocode()` returned `undefined`. My solution is to wrap this function with `Promise`.

```
    declare const require : any;

        @Injectable()
        export class GoogleMapLocationResolver implements Resolve<{location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number }> {

        constructor( private locationService: LocationService, 
                     private route: ActivatedRoute, 
                     private router: Router){}

        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): {location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number } | Observable<{location: Location, longitude:number, latitude: number }> | Promise<{location: Location, longitude: number, latitude: number }> {

            let geocoder = require('geocoder');

            return this.locationService.getLocation(route.params['id']).map(
                (response: Response)=> { return response.json() }
            ).mergeMap( location => new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {geocoder.geocode(location.address, function(err, data){
                let latitude
                let longitude
                if(data.status === 'OK'){
                    console.log('Status ok: ')
                    console.log(data)
                    let results = data.results;
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                    console.log(latitude); 
                    console.log(longitude); 
                }                  
                resolve({location, longitude, latitude}(;
    })
            })).catch(error => {
                this.router.navigate(['/not-found'])
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })  
          }
```